# Is this scheduling problem with arrival times, deadlines, and costs NP-hard?

Tags: algorithms, np-hard

There are $n$ jobs where each job $i$ has an arrival time $r_i$, a deadline $d_i$ and a cost $c_i$. The problem is to find a scheduling time $t_i$ (where $r_i\leq t_i\leq d_i$) for each job $i$ in order to minimize $$\sum_i\max_{j\in S_i}(c_j),$$ where $S_i$ is the set of jobs scheduled at time $t_i$.

Can we solve this problem in polynomial-time or is it NP-hard?

For example, if all jobs can be scheduled at the same time $t$, then the objective will be $\max(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n)$. The issue is that all jobs cannot always be scheduled at the same time $t$ because of their arrival times and deadlines. If I schedule the jobs as they arrive, I may end up with the objective of $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i$, which is the largest possible. So, the problem is somehow how to partition the jobs into sets $S_i$ (where jobs in $S_i$ are scheduled at the same time) for which we obtain the minimum objective. As such, I am trying to reduce Partition to this scheduling problem but still did not find the right reduction. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Do jobs have a length as well? How many jobs can performed at the same time? The information given seems strange to me.

Comment: Jobs have the same length (say 1). You can schedule as many jobs as you want in a single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following observation enables a polynomial-time algorithm:

Whenever the time slot $t_i$ for a job $i$ has been chosen, it's optimal to assign the same time slot for all lower-cost jobs that overlap $t_i$, as doing so will incur zero additional cost.  Therefore, choosing the time slot for the most costly job "magnetises" all the jobs that can be assigned the same time slot, and partitions the remaining jobs into two sets: those whose intervals are completely to the left of this time slot, and those whose intervals are completely to the right.  The subproblems for these two sets of jobs can then be solved independently.

A general subproblem can be described by an interval $(a, b)$ and a maximum cost $c$: the jobs in this subproblem consist of all those jobs whose intervals fall within $(a, b)$ and which have cost at most $c$.  The optimal solution for a subproblem can be found by trying every possible time slot for the most costly job in the subproblem, and solving the corresponding 2 subproblems for each attempt.  A plain recursive strategy would take exponenential time, but there are only $O(n^3)$ distinct subproblems to solve: There are only $O(n)$ "basic intervals" (maximal intervals that do not cross the beginning or end of any job interval) to consider, so there are at most $O(n^2)$ possible intervals (blocks) of these, and $O(n)$ possible different job costs.  Thus dynamic programming can be applied.  It should be possible to test each of the $O(n)$ possible time slots available for the most costly job in $O(1)$ time each, excluding the time needed to solve subproblems, for $O(n^4)$ time and $O(n^3)$ space overall -- not fast, but certainly polynomial.

Comment: It seems $c$ is needless for your subproblem. How can you test each time slot in $O(1)$ since you need to partition all the jobs?

Comment: @xskxzr: I think you're right about $c$ being unnecessary.  I should have written $O(1)$ *amortised* time for testing each time slot -- this shouldn't be hard, since the *changes in* the two sets can be easily found by walking a sorted list of endpoints.  You don't need to start partitioning afresh for each slot.

Comment: Can you apply your algorithm to some example? I did this on the following 3-jobs instance. Job $i$ is denoted as $(r_i,d_i,c_i)$. Job 1 is given by $(1, 2, 1)$. Job 2 is given by $(2, 3, 3)$. And job 3 is given by $(3, 3, 2)$. Your algorithm (if I am not mistaken) schedules job 1 and job 2 at $2$ and job 3 at $3$, which gives the total cost of $\max(1,3)+2=5$. However, if job 1 is scheduled at $2$ and job 2 and job 3 are scheduled at $3$, then the total cost will be $1+\max(2,3)=4$.

Comment: Also, how do you find the scheduling time of the most costly job?

Comment: @zdm: In your example, the overall problem corresponds to a subproblem spanning from 1 to 3, with the most costly job being job 2.  So we first try both of job 2's possible timeslots (2 and 3) first, noting that we must pay 3 regardless of what we do here.  First, let's try setting it to timeslot 2.  In that case, job 1 is "magnetised" to timeslot 2 as well for an additional cost of 0, leaving job 3 in the right-hand-side partition and an empty left-hand-side partition.  The subproblem corresponding to that RHS partition (consisting of just job 3) costs 2, so...

Comment: ...  the total cost for the subproblem in which we assign job 2 to timeslot 2 is 3+2=5.  We now try assigning job 2 to timeslot 3: This results in job 3 being magnetised to the same timeslot, leaving job 1 in the LHS partition and an empty RHS partition.  The cost for the subproblem corresponding to this LHS partition, which contains just job 1, is clearly 1, so overall this placement of job 3 gives a total cost of 3+1=4.  As this is the lowest cost placement of job 3 seen for this subproblem, we assign its cost as the subproblem's (and in this case the overall problem's) cost.

Comment: "how do you find the scheduling time of the most costly job" -- you try all possibilities, and measure each :)  If you didn't get this from my explanation of the algorithm, then perhaps it's not clear enough yet -- I'll try to break it down a bit further when I have time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your proposed algorithm? I don't understand how can this be polytime? For the most costly job we have to try all possibilities and for each possibility, we have to run the algorithm recursively.

Comment: "and for each possibility, we have to run the algorithm recursively" -- not if we save the results of solving each subproblem and use that saved value the next time we need it instead of solving it all over again, which is exactly what dynamic programming does.  There are only $O(n^2)$ possible distinct subproblems to solve (I originally wrote $O(n^3)$ but I think xskxzr's comment is correct).

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to apply dynamic programming as you mentioned but I cannot find the recursion relation. What I have so far is. Let $S_j$ denotes the jobs scheduled at $t_j$ and $S_j^{-}$ and $S_j^{+}$ denote the jobs to be scheduled before and after $t_j$, respectively. Then, the cost of the original problem to schedule all the jobs in $S$ is $c(S)=c_j+c(S_j^{-})+c(S_j^{+})$. How can I continue?

Comment: Hi @j_random_hacker. I tried to compute the complexity of your algorithm but I didn't understand the following: If I split the $n$ jobs equally in each time, I will have $n/2$ and $n/2$, etc. So, finally I will have $O(n)$ subproblems, right? Why do you said $O(n^2)$? Thanks.